# Getting Array as a raw command line argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, arguments

I am trying to implement raw command line arguments in Node.js.

When I implement simple variables everything works

```
(node example.js variable)
```

But when I implement as an argument an array it doesn't work

```
(node example.js "['127.0.0.5', '127.0.0.3']" )
```

Full code:

```
if (process.argv.length <= 3) {
    console.log("Usage: " + __filename + " SOME_PARAM");
    process.exit(-1);
}

var variable = process.argv[2];
var array = process.argv[3];

console.log('Host: ' + variable);
console.log('array: ' + array);
```

**Problem**

Example of input of arguments ( `node example.js variable "['127.0.0.5', '127.0.0.3']"` )

How to pass the second argument (`"['127.0.0.5', '127.0.0.3']"`) as an array rather than as a string (as it is now), so that later I might access array's n-th element (example `array[0] = '127.0.0.5'` )

**SOLUTION**

The input should be like ( `'["127.0.0.5", "127.0.0.3"]'` changing the quotes), and also we need to parse the argument as JSON.

```
if (process.argv.length <= 3) {
    console.log("Usage: " + __filename + " SOME_PARAM");
    process.exit(-1);
}

var variable = process.argv[2];
var array = JSON.parse(process.argv[4]);

console.log('Host: ' + variable);
console.log('array: ' + array);
console.log(array[1]
```

Comment: You can't "pass it as an array" but you can parse the argument to build your array. You get a string no matter what, it's up to you to convert it into an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to pass an array. What you have to do (and possibly are in the middle of doing) is passing something like an array converted to a JSON string.

And in the application, you would just do a [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get your array out of the string.

Answer (score 11):

It's an old question, but if someone still looking for a simple solution, here it is.

Pass named arguments multiple times with same name.

```
node example.js --variable=127.0.0.5 --variable=127.0.0.3
```

Use [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist) NPM package to extract args as:

```js
const parseArgs = require('minimist');

const args = parseArgs(process.argv.slice(2));
console.log(args.variable);
```

Output:

```
[ '127.0.0.5', '127.0.0.3' ]
```

Comment: Tried to Edit the post but "edit queue are full' so I'll put it a a comment. You may need to add a ```--``` for npm to recognise the command line variable. ```node example.js -- --variable=127.0.0.5 --variable=127.0.0.3```

Comment: For an array where you only need to pass the values I converted the whole thing to a comma separated string with implode and on the JS side then did a string.split(','), with that I was able to feed a Node script the values I got from a PHP array. I guess for a simple case this could be done..